# How do I loop through a pandas dataframe, check to see if the data type of each column is a float number, then replace null values with mean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a pandas Dataframe which has columns with different data types, and replace them with different data types based on their null values.

```
for col in WHO_df:
    if WHO_df[col].dtype == 'float64':
        WHO_df[col].fillna(WHO_df[col].mean())
    else:
        WHO_df[col].fillna(0)
```

This code did not work as the null values are not replaced in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fillna() doesn't normaly edit your dataframe.
you have 2 ways:

```
for col in WHO_df:
if WHO_df[col].dtype == 'float64':
    WHO_df[col] = WHO_df[col].fillna(WHO_df[col].mean())
else:
    WHO_df[col] = WHO_df[col].fillna(0)
```

or:

```
for col in WHO_df:
if WHO_df[col].dtype == 'float64':
    WHO_df[col].fillna(WHO_df[col].mean(),inplace=True)
else:
    WHO_df[col].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```